# elasticsearch index getting reset

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a single node elasticsearch instance ( 0.90 version) running on a single machine ( 8GB RAM, dual core CPU) having RHEL 5.6

After having indexed close to 2 million documents, it runs fine for a few hours and then restarts on its own, wiping out the index in the process. I now need to reindex all the documents again.

Any ideas on why this happens? Maximum file descriptors is set to 32k and the number of open file descriptors at any time does not even come close. So it cant be that.

Here are the modifications i made to the default elasticsearch.yml file :

```
index.number_of_shards: 5 
index.cache.field.type: soft 
index.fielddata.cache: soft 
index.cache.field.expire: 5m 
indices.fielddata.cache.size: 10% 
indices.fielddata.cache.expire : 5m 
index.store.type: mmapfs 
bootstrap.mlockall: true 
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false 
action.disable_delete_all_indices: true 
script.disable_dynamic: true
```

I use the elasticsearch service wrapper to start and stop the instance. In the elasticsearch.conf file, i have set the heap size to 2GB :

```
set.default.ES_HEAP_SIZE=2048
```

Any help in diagnosing the problem will be appreciated. 
Thanks guys!

Comment: all the data just disappears? whats in the data directory of your node? Is that directory getting wiped out by something? Have you explicitly set the data directory to someplace strange (like /tmp) in your config file?

Comment: currently the output looks like this : http://pastebin.com/jkWaNqwG , but when the index is reset, the {_all : primaries : docs : count} reduces to < 200 and the {store : size} becomes a few KB.  Data directory is under the elasticsearch install - "/usr/local/elasticsearch-0.90.5/data"  ( remember, i haven't modified the default yml other than whats specified).  I seriously doubt something is wiping out that directory.

Comment: eventually figured this one out. Apparently when you call the delete API with an empty id parameter, it deletes the entire type and the mapping along with it. This basically resets the index. So in my code I started explicitly filtering for empty ids and this seems to have solved the problem.